# Is it possible to set a primary key to a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, materialized-views

Is it possible to set a primary key to a view in SQLServer 2008?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a **clustered index** on a SQL Server view - it's called an indexed view.

See [Improving Performance with SQL Server 2008 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: And unique constraints can be applied as well so that's 99% of the way there.

Comment: Yes, once the clustered index is in place, other indices can be added - including unique indices

Comment: +1: SQL Server calls it an indexed view, but it's generally referred to as being a Materialized View.  But there are constraints to materialized/indexed views: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx#XSLTsection126121120120